# Pagination on Codeigniter always selected on page 1

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

I've a problem with pagination.
It show the data on database by its limit,but it always select page 1 even i click the second page.

I'm using sorting and pagination in 1 function
This is my controller

```
    function index($sort_by = 'title', $sort_order= 'asc', $offset = 0)
    {
        $limit = 2;

        $data['fields'] = array(
            'nama' => 'Nama',
            'jabatan' => 'Jabatan',
            'jampulang' => 'Jam Pulang',
            'alasan' => 'Alasan',
            'pendingtask' => 'Pending Task',
            'status' => 'Status'
        );

        $result = $this->karyawan_pulang->search($limit,$offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);

        $data['pulang'] = $result['rows'];
        $data['num_results'] = $result['num_rows'];
        $data['main_content'] = 'karyawanpulangarea';

        // pagination
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("izinpulang/index/$sort_by/$sort_order");
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_results'];
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['url_segment'] = 4;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['sort_by'] = $sort_by;
        $data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;

        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }
```

And this is my model

```
function search($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order)
{
    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $sort_columns = array('nama', 'jabatan', 'jampulang', 'alasan', 'pendingtask', 'status');
    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'nama';

    // result query
    $q = $this->db->select('pid, nama, jabatan, jampulang, alasan, pendingtask, status')
        ->from('izin_pulang')
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();

    // count query
    $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
        ->from('izin_pulang');

    $tmp = $q->get()->result();
    $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0] -> count;


    return $ret;
}
```

This is my view

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/form_area"><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/backs.png'/>Back</a></h2>
<h3>
<?php

if (empty($pulang)) {

echo "There's No Data!";


}

else 
{

?>
</h3>
<div id="content" class="container_center">
<h3> Daftar Karyawan Izin Pulang</h3>
<div id="count">
    Jumlah Data : <?php echo $num_results;?>
</div>
<div class="table">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr align="center">
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display):?>
        <th <?php if($sort_by == $field_name) echo "class=\"sort_$sort_order\""?>>
            <?php echo anchor("izinpulang/index/$field_name/" .
                (($sort_order == 'asc' && $sort_by == $field_name) ? 'desc' : 'asc') ,
            $field_display); ?>
        </th>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php

foreach ($pulang as $data):

?>
<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display):?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $data->$field_name; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
         <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>izinpulang/baca/<?php echo $data->pid; ?> "><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/edit.png'/></a></td>
         <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>izinpulang/download/<?php echo $data->pid; ?>"><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/downloads.png'/></a> </td>         
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php

endforeach;

?>

</table>
<?php if (strlen($pagination)):?>
<div id="count">
    Pages : <?php echo $pagination;?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php

}
?>
<br>
</div>
```

I try to change the url_segment just like google and people recommend it.
But however its still not working. But if i only do some pagination and not do sorting

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url("izinpulang/index/");
```

The pagination is working but doesn't load the second data on page 2. It show the same data as page 1.

Any advice ? Thank you

Comment: I guess, your `url_segment` should be `5`. Please try

Comment: not working either @Bora , i try to change it from 1 - 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codes wrong, you should use `uri_segment` instead of `url_segment`

```
$config['uri_segment']
```

Comment: i'd like to but i haven't reach 15 reputation yet =/
Because i'm new here.

Comment: Sharp eyes dude +1 :D @Bora

Comment: @Bora, can you help me a lil bit.
What should i do if i want to show the data by its id ?
I try to show a data by its id and do some pagination, but the pagination isn't working. I give a limit by 2 but the data show all of em

"$data['dwp'] = $this->db->get_where('dwp', array('eid' => $session_data['id']))->result();"

This is the code for showing the data by its id.

but this "$data['dwp'] = $result['rows'];" show all of the data.
What should i do ??

Comment: You should use limit and offset on query.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you really need

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5
```

but be sure that `$sort_by/$sort_order` are always present or your pagination uri segment will change

you should do better:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url("izinpulang/index");
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['suffix'] = "/$sort_by/$sort_order";
```

and your urls will looks like for example : `site.com/izinpulang/index/10/sort_by/sort_order`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $config["base_url"] = base_url();
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->authors_model->get_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

hi make changes its uri_segment not url_segment, and for base_url use bese_url helper

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url("izinpulang/index/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Just use this inside your `$config` & boom! It will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

you should use change this

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5
```